# Why is Sri Krishna called as Kalamanika?

Tags: krishna, name

What is KalaManika?

What is the significance of referring Lord Krishna as Kalamanika?

Edit

Reference

A village student of 7th class studying in Oriya medium, once asked me this question.

This question is from a poem named "Kalamanika re" in 7th class Oriya medium in Orissa board.

I was trying to upload the a captured image of the question but some error occurred. I think due to mobile slow network. I will try to upload again later.

Comment: Please provide your source where you found this name and possible alternative ways of transcribing it.

Comment: Kaalaa (black) + Manika (gem)..seems like inherited from his colour..

Comment: @YDS That is the right answer post it as an answer, We don't need separate scriptural sources to say that Kaalaa = black and mani is a gem.

Comment: @Kailash [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HT6iTksD0BI) is the poem/song right?

Comment: @YDS, https://youtu.be/3kcvcL7BU20 link is the one